# In Xul, how do I make a XPCOM component call a javascript function?

Tags: xul, listener, observer-pattern, xpcom

I want to implement a listener/observer for my XPCOM component, so my javascript code can register to be notified of some events. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_JavaScript_callbacks_in_components might be just the thing you are looking for.